# Store all resource files in one executing assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, embedded-resource

Is it possible to store all resource information in one executing assembly. To store resx files in different dll files (per language) is not suitable in my case.

Comment: I can't help but doubting that "not suitable in my case". You are in control of what is being deployed to the bin folder, and on the Web that's even more true than for the Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You just need to make it publicly visible by setting the generator to: `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`:

[image]

This will make Visual Studio generate public classes and not internal for your resources making them accessible in other assemblies.

Comment: Currently i am using this, and it create new dll per language

Comment: When I use this option VS store only EN version of localization in application exe, for additional languages VS creates folder and dll in it with localization information

Comment: That's how resources work in .NET. Those are called satellite assemblies and are generated for each language. You need to deploy those assemblies as well. But if you reference the project that contains those resources in your web application, the satellite assemblies will be automatically copied as well. What is important is that they are present in the `bin` folder of your web application when you deploy. If you don't want to have multiple assemblies for each language then you will have to invent some other mechanism for localizing your application and not rely on what's built-in.